# Groovy name queried

Tags: grails, select, groovy

I got a domain like this:

```
ZZPartAndTeam
    String parts
    String team
```

Parts may have many team.

```
For ex: part:part1 team:10
        part:part1 team:20
        part:part2 team:30
```

How can I query in the domain that get all parts which have multi team?

```
result:part:part1 team:10
       part:part1 team:20
```

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  what is a "multi team"?  your "domain" there has `String parts` and later you talk about `part:`.  this example is incomplete hard to comprehend

Answer (score 0):

The HAVING clause is not supported by Hibernate Criteria. A way around is to use DetachedCriteria.

```
          import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria as HDetachedCriteria

          query: { builder, params ->

              // This query counts the number of teams per part
              HDetachedCriteria innerQry = HDetachedCriteria.forClass(ZZPartAndTeam.class)
              innerQry.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.count('team').as('teamCount'))
              )
              innerQry.add(HRestrictions.eqProperty('part', 'outer.part')

              // Using innerQuery, this criteria returns the parts having more than one team.
              HDetachedCriteria outerQry = HDetachedCriteria.forClass(ZZPartAndTeam.class, 'outer')
              outerQry.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property('part').as('part')))
              )
              outerQry.add(Subqueries.gt(1, innerQry))

              builder.addToCriteria(Property.forName('part').in(outerQry))
          }
```